# Can interface type and value be a type that does not implement the interface and its value?

Tags: go, methods, go-interface

Here is the link to the code and description I was looking at: https://tour.golang.org/methods/11

I change method M of type *T to T, that is changing from a pointer receiver to a value receiver as below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type I interface {
    M()
}

type T struct {
    S string
}

func (t T) M() {
    fmt.Println(t.S)
}

type F float64

func (f F) M() {
    fmt.Println(f)
}

func main() {
    var i I

    i = &T{"Hello"}
    describe(i)
    i.M()

    i = F(math.Pi)
    describe(i)
    i.M()
}

func describe(i I) {
    fmt.Printf("(%v, %T)\n", i, i)
}
```

However, the change above gave me the same result as it was still a pointer receiver.

```
(&{Hello}, *main.T)
Hello
(3.141592653589793, main.F)
3.141592653589793
```

I am not sure I got this concept right. From my understanding since interface variable i got assign a pointer to an instance of struct T, the type of that interface variable should be a pointer to struct T, and since pointer to struct T does not implement method M, it will cause a panic.

Answer (score 1):

[Spec: Method sets:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

> The method set of the corresponding [pointer type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) `*T` is the set of all methods declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).
>
> [...] The method set of a type determines the interfaces that the type [implements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) and the methods that can be [called](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) using a receiver of that type.

So all methods you declare with value receiver will also belong to the method set of the corresponding pointer type, and thus all interfaces a non-pointer type implements will also be implemented by the pointer type too (and possibly more).

Answer (score 0):

Go has some shortcuts. For example:

```
a.Method()
a.Field
```

is the same as

```
(*a).Method()
(*a).Field
```

is similar to the concept here https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/4